# Cannot get a CSS class from Google search page

Tags: python, beautifulsoup, spell-checking

I use [BeautifulSoup](https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/) for parsing a Google search, but I get empty list. I want to make a spellchecker by using Google's "Did you mean?".

```html
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import urllib.parse


text = "i an you ate goode maan"
data = urllib.parse.quote_plus(text)

url = 'https://translate.google.com/?source=osdd#view=home&op=translate&sl=auto&tl=en&text='

rq = requests.get(url + data)

soup = BeautifulSoup(rq.content, 'html.parser')

words = soup.select('.tlid-spelling-correction spelling-correction gt-spell-correct-message')

print(words)
```

The output is just: [], but expected: "i and you are good man" (sorry for such a bad text example)

Answer (score 0):

First, the element you are looking for is loaded using javascript. Since BeautifulSoup does not run js, the target elements don't get loaded into the DOM hence the query selector can't find them. Try using [Selenium](https://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/) instead of BeautifulSoup.

Second, The CSS selector should be

```
.tlid-spelling-correction.spelling-correction.gt-spell-correct-message`.
```

Notice the `.` instead of space in front of every class name.

I have verified it using JS query selector

[image]

The selector you were using `.tlid-spelling-correction spelling-correction gt-spell-correct-message` was looking for an element with class `gt-spell-correct-message` inside an element with class `spelling-correction` which itself was inside another element with class `tlid-spelling-correction`.

By removing the space and putting a dot in front of every class name, the selector looks for an element with all three of the above mentioned classes.

Comment: Hello, still get the same result, same empty list.